# Getting error "id can not be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android

I am getting an error of "id can not be resolved or is not a field" in my private `View.OnClickListner onSave = new View.OnclickListner()`.

I am getting the error "Illegal modifier for parameter onSave; only final is permitted".

ID's in the `activity.java` file and layout file are also same.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

    private View.OnClickListener onSave  = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.add);
```

**LAYOUT CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow
                <TextView android:text="Name    :        " />
                <EditText android:id="@+id/name"></EditText>
             ></TableRow>

            <TableRow
                <TextView android:text="Address    :    "/>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/add"</EditText>
            ></TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save" />
        ></TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In future, please spend more time writing or formatting your post. Formatting help can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2):

Your button's id is `button1`, not `save`, so this line:

```
Button save =(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
```

should be

```
Button save =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Or, if you want to be more clear, you can change it to:

```
android:id="@+id/save_button"
```

and

```
Button save =(Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
```

Comment: thnx ,but still left wid an error on same line R can not be resolved to a variable. n i have lost my R.java file

Comment: just give it a few seconds to re-generate the R class. if it's not, clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet : he is not closing Edittext tag as xml provided in question